# CommitFailedException by Spring Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I get the below error message sometimes while using Spring Kafka Consumer .I have implemented at least once semantics as shown in the code snippet

1 )My doubt is do I miss any message from consuming?

2)Do i need to handle this error .As this error was not reported by `seekToCurrentErrorHandler()`

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit
> cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group
> for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was
> kicked out of the group.

My spring kafka consumer code snippet

```
  public class KafkaConsumerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer 
    @Bean
        public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler() {
            SeekToCurrentErrorHandler seekToCurrentErrorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, e) -> {
                System.out.println("RECORD from topic " + record.topic() + " at partition " + record.partition()
                        + " at offset " + record.offset() + " did not process correctly due to a " + e.getCause());
            }, new FixedBackOff(500L, 3L));
            return seekToCurrentErrorHandler;
        }
    
        @Bean 
        public ConsumerFactory<String, ValidatedConsumerClass> consumerFactory() {
      
      ErrorHandlingDeserializer<ValidatedConsumerClass> errorHandlingDeserializer;
      errorHandlingDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>( new JsonDeserializer<>(ValidatedConsumerClass.class));
      
      Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grpid-098");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
      
      
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
      errorHandlingDeserializer);
      
      }
    
        @Bean
        KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, ValidatedConsumerClass>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ValidatedConsumerClass> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
            factory.setErrorHandler(seekToCurrentErrorHandler());
            return factory;
        }
```

Consumer reading the message

```
@Service
public class KafKaConsumerService extends  AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "mytopic-5", concurrency = "5", groupId = "mytopic-1-groupid")
    public void consumeFromTopic1(@Payload @Valid ValidatedConsumerClass message, ConsumerRecordMetadata c) {


        
    databaseService.save(message);
        
        System.out.println( "-- Consumer End -- "   + c.partition() + " ---consumer thread-- " + Thread.currentThread().getName());


    }
```

Comment: It means that your consumer took too long to process the message and the broker performed a rebalance; it must process `max.poll.records` within `max.poll.interval.ms`. It seems odd since the former is only 1 and the latter defaults to 5 miniutes, and all you are doing is saving to a DB, unless your validation is taking a lot of time.

Comment: @GaryRussell Correct.DB servers were slow.But you didn't answer my question.I know the reason.Can you please answer 1 and 2 points in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you are not missing anything.
2. No, you do not need to handle it, the STCEH already handled it and the record will be redelivered on the next poll.

In this case, the exception is caused outside of record processing (after processing is complete). Since the commit failed due to a rebalance, there is no need for the STCEH to reseeek (and it can't anyway because the records are no longer available). It simply rethrows the exception.

Everything works as expected...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=5000
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69016372Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69016372Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so69016372", topics = "so69016372")
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(in + " @" + offset);
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so69016372").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

Result

```
2021-09-01 13:47:26.963  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions assigned: [so69016372-0]
foo @0
2021-09-01 13:47:31.991  INFO 13195 --- [ad | so69016372] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Member consumer-so69016372-1-f02f8d74-c2b8-47d9-92d3-bf68e5c81a8f sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2021-09-01 13:47:32.989  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
2021-09-01 13:47:32.994 ERROR 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:200) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1602) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1139) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1004) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1495) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2710) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2705) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2691) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2489) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1235) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2021-09-01 13:47:32.994  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group
2021-09-01 13:47:32.994  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Lost previously assigned partitions so69016372-0
2021-09-01 13:47:32.995  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions lost: [so69016372-0]
2021-09-01 13:47:32.995  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions revoked: [so69016372-0]
...
2021-09-01 13:47:33.102  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions assigned: [so69016372-0]
foo @0
2021-09-01 13:47:38.141  INFO 13195 --- [ad | so69016372] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Member consumer-so69016372-1-e6ec685a-d9aa-43d3-b526-b04418095f09 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
2021-09-01 13:47:39.108  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
2021-09-01 13:47:39.109 ERROR 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:200) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1602) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1139) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1004) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1495) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2710) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2705) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2691) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2489) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1235) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2021-09-01 13:47:39.109  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group
2021-09-01 13:47:39.109  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-so69016372-1, groupId=so69016372] Lost previously assigned partitions so69016372-0
2021-09-01 13:47:39.109  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions lost: [so69016372-0]
2021-09-01 13:47:39.109  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions revoked: [so69016372-0]
...
2021-09-01 13:47:39.217  INFO 13195 --- [o69016372-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : so69016372: partitions assigned: [so69016372-0]
foo @0
```

It will retry indefinitely.

Comment: I am able to see logs printed in STCEH for all errors except CommitFailedException.Is this an expected behaviour.

Comment: It works as expected - see the example in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Russel. Thanks for the explanation. Understood. So basically Kafka will re-read  the same message again but it  won't miss it.

Comment: Correct; since the commit failed, any non-committed offsets will be redelivered after the rebalance.

Comment: Your 2nd point  isn't true anymore i guess ` STCEH already handled it and the record will be redelivered on the next poll.`And I didn't understood what do you mean by `It will retry indefinitely.`

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue and it went into infinite loop.

Comment: Is there anyway i can avoid infinite loop .That is move to next message?

Comment: No. If the DB is taking too long, you will have the same problem on the next record too. You could do a seek after a rebalance but there is nothing built in for that. You really need to solve the root cause.

Comment: Actually, the retrying that Spring does is not what it seems.

It tries to redo the poll, which immediately fails for not being part of a consumer group. The KafkaConsumer that Spring uses under the hood is basically as dead as the Parrot in the Monty Python sketch.

It does not try to re-handle the record that originally caused the problem.

Is there a way to tell Spring to create a new KafkaConsumer and ignoring the old one? If not, the only way to recover from this error is to restart the application - and that's something I wouldn't want to have to do...

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers; there is no need to create a new consumer,  another rebalance will occur when this consumer does the next poll. If you are still seeing problems I suggest you ask a new question with much more information (configuration, logs, etc.).